# Can someone explain me which are the steps to create a trigger in cassandra v3.11?

Tags: cassandra, triggers, cassandra-3.0

I have to create a trigger for my database in cassandra, but the doc does not help me.

After creating the keyspace, the tables and tried to do insert on the test table and gives me the following error:

Following the example to which the datastax documentation refers, I have done all the steps and it works.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers

Then I copied the created .jar file and the .proprierties file and copied them to the respective directories of my ubuntu18 server as suggested in the last two steps of the readme file.

After creating the keyspace, the tables and tried to do insert on the test table and gives me the following error:

ServerError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/schema/Schema

Why this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: The question no